# Auth::attempt() return false always

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

alaways returning false values but values are coming correct through $request what should I do?

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');//singh@gmail.com
        $password = $request->input('password');//a

        //$input = ['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password];

        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>'singhkulpreet05@gmail.com','password'=>$password])) {
            return "logged in";
        }
        else return "notttt";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first check your DB and below code works for me. You can try it & hopefully it'll work.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){

    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')))){
        return "logged in"; 
    }

    return "notttt";
}
```

Comment: Same issue is arrising with this solution.
Thaku for the reply:)

Comment: Today i spotted the cause of issue and the issue is "hash password". Earlier I'm trying to store password without encryption.
Now it's solved.